Pushforward of a density by a linear transformation
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random variable with probability measure $\pi_{X}$.
For $r \leq n$, we define the random variable $Z_r = \varphi_r(X) = U_r^\top X \in \mathbb{R}^r$ where $U_r \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ is a matrix of $r$ orthonormal columns. We denote by $U_\perp \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-r) \times n}$ an orthogonal completion such that $U = [U_r, U_\perp] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ forms an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus the pre-image $\varphi_r^{-1}(z_r)$ is given by $\varphi_r^{-1}(z_r) = \{ U_r z_r + U_\perp z_\perp | z_\perp \in \mathbb{R}^{n-r} \}$.
The measure of $Z_r$, denoted $\pi_{Z_r}$, is given by the pushforward of $\pi_X$ by the transformation $\varphi_r$, i.e., $\pi_{Z_r}(z_r) = \varphi_{r, \sharp} \pi_X(z_r)$
I would like to show that $\varphi_{r, \sharp} \pi_X(z_r) = \int \pi_
{X}(U_r z_r + U_\perp z_\perp) \mathrm{d} z_\perp$, i.e. the pushforward measure is given by the marginal distribution of the first $r$ components of $Z = U^\top X$.
We start from the definition of the pushforward density
\begin{align}
\pi_{Z_r}(z_r) = \varphi_{r, \sharp} \pi_X(z_r) & = \pi_{X}(\varphi_r^{-1}(z_r)) \det \nabla_{z_r} \varphi_r^{-1}(z_r)\\
\end{align}
I understand that the term $\pi_{X}(\varphi_r^{-1}(z_r))$ is equal to $\int \pi_{X}(U_r z_r + U_\perp z_\perp) d z_\perp$ from the characterization of the pre-image $\varphi_r^{-1}(z_r)$ given above.
I don’t know how to make sense of the Jacobian term $\det \nabla_{z_r} \varphi_r^{-1}(z_r)$ involving the pre-image, especially because $\varphi_r \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^r$.
I would appreciate your help with this derivation

If $r = n$ and $U_r = I_r$ is the identity matrix, isn't it the case that $\pi_X(U_rz_r + U_\perp z_\perp) = 0$? Or $\pi_X$ is here the density of $X$?

For $r = n$, $U_r$ is a $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix, but not necessarily the identity, and $U_\perp$ is a $n \times 0$ matrix such that $\pi_{Z_n}(z_n) = \pi_{X}(U_n z_n)$. We are simply expressing the measure $\pi_{X}$ in a rotated space.

geometrically, it seems its basically rotating the density and then summarizing (integrating over) the density in the space orthogonal to projection.

and since the linear transform is rotation + projection that determinant term should be 1.
